# Automatically run a PHP script every time a user change a row in MySQL/WordPress database

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a small web app to feed one website from a row of a database in another website (a WordPress based website).

Essentially I have three files: one called `outputjson.php` that will generate a JSON file called `results.json` (that live in my WordPress website) and in another website I will make an AJAX request for that file in order to display an announcers section for a radio station (with pictures of the announcer, socials, time).

My problem is that I have to manually initiate the process but I would like to do it automatically, every time anyone will update my database, I want that my file will listen to the event and run the PHP script.

So far my code is:

outputjson.php

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
if(!isset($wpdb))
{
    require_once('wp-config.php');
    require_once('wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM " . $table_prefix . "radio_announcer_on_air" );

$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Which will generate a file like:

results.json

```
    [  
       {  
          "announcer_id":"19",
          "announcer_time_start":"07:00:00",
          "announcer_time_end":"08:59:59",
          "announcer_photo":"image.jpg",
          "announcer_name":"Name",
          "announcer_facebook":"",
          "announcer_twitter":"",
          "announcer_rss":"",
          "announcer_mail":"",
          "announcer_weekday":"7"
       }
]
```

My last file will live on another server and will make the magic:

announcers.js

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://otherwebsite.com/results.json",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      cache: false,
      success: function(markers) {
//Do something
}
```

Any suggestion? I could even consider running this script every day for example, since running it every time someone is going to change my database row (the event) sounds very complicated, at least for my knowledge that I've got so far.

Comment: crontab can help you?

Comment: Personally, id use RPC to directly insert the data into the other database.

Comment: I've never used an RPC, do you know where I can find a documentation about it?

Comment: I just want to use php, mysql and javascript by the way, my server is really basic

Comment: I second the crontab suggestion. This is the going to be the easiest solution. Write a script to look for new entires in your DB, and run your process whenever it finds them.  Schedule to run it regularly in crontab

Comment: Does the file have to be called `results.json`? If you can call it `results.json.php` then you could just generate the file whenever it is requested by the AJAX operation. You could still call it `results.json` if you wish, but you will need some `mod_rewrite` trickery to get the file to be processed by PHP.

Comment: Sure I can call it however I want, but it's a json file.. Can I call a json file something.json.php?

Comment: Thanks! I'll be waiting!

Comment: @Matto it doesn't have to be .json. You can have php output your information as json with appropriate headers set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great thing about consuming a JSON endpoint in a browser is that it does not have to come from a static file.

Consider your `results.json` example. If this is a static file, then your web server (usually Apache) will detect the `json` extension and send the appropriate [MIME type header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) to identify its type to the browser. For JSON, that is:

```
application/json
```

So, as long as we do the same in PHP, an AJAX call in JavaScript won't notice the difference. In `outputjson.php`, just add this at the start:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

This is necessary since the web server will see that the file extension is `php` and will not know what MIME type that corresponds to (since a PHP script can generate a file of any type). Thus, we have to do that manually.

To wire it into your JavaScript, simply point the `url` parameter to your PHP script:

```
url: "http://otherwebsite.com/outputjson.php",
```

I mentioned in the comments that a file could be called `something.json.php`. To clarify, this naming style is just a convention, and does not actually get the web server to set any headers automatically - you still have to do that in your PHP script. However, the naming makes it very easy for developers and site users to see (in a URL bar or file explorer) what type of content the file generates.

### New script

So, your updated script will be something like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

global $wpdb;
require_once 'wp-config.php';
require_once 'wp-includes/wp-db.php';

$result = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}radio_announcer_on_air"
);

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Notice that it no longer has to write to a file - it should just output the data to the browser. I removed `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` since I did not understand the purpose of that - put it back if you are sure you need it, but the PHP defaults are usually good.

I've removed the `if` statement as well, since there is no way for the global database variable to be set until the WP libraries are loaded.

### Addendum

It would be worth considering how often this endpoint is to be consumed by AJAX, and how much of a load it puts on your database. If it were to contain more than a few hundred rows, you might want to think about pagination, since AJAX operations handling large amounts of data can slow the browser down.

However, it is wise to get it working first, and then you can optimise from there if it proves necessary.

Comment: I try to run your script but it didn't work. I modify my outputjson.php, which create the .json file. I changed the name of the json file in result.json.php (but I don't think that the file is involved anymore in the process ) and the last thing that I did is to change my ajax call in my other server to point the php file instead of the json file.

The thing is that the outputjson.php will create the json file in another file. I didn't quite understand that part. When I wrote the code I thought to manually run that file every time someone updates the plugin (it's a wordpress plugin to

Comment: insert all the announcers in my radio website on wordpress). And now I want to do it automatically. But I didn't quite understand the step that you described me, which is the one when my ajax file will point to a php file. Could you be more precise?

Comment: OK, no worries. The next step is some debugging, for which you will need your browser's Network tab open. Then do the action in your web page that triggers the AJAX request and examine (a) the request going to the web server, and (b) the response. The most common mistake is a response of 404, which means that the URL target did not correspond to a PHP script on the other side.

Comment: Should I create a php and merge the php script and the json file?

Comment: Cool let me try

Comment: "Should I create a php and merge the php script and the json file" - no, follow the instructions in my post. Your PHP file, with the `header()` on the first line (after `<?php` of course) is the correct approach.

Comment: ok, now my php file looks like this:
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
global $wpdb;
if(!isset($wpdb))
{
 require_once('wp-config.php');
 require_once('wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM " . $table_prefix . "radio_announcer_on_air" );

$fp = fopen('results.json.php', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
fclose($fp);
?>

Comment: Ah, you will need to change that to output the JSON, not write it to a file. I will update my answer.

Comment: Perfect it seems it working fine. So the result.json is not involved anymore in the process, was I right? Do I need it anymore?

Comment: @Matto, correct - that file can be deleted, and the PHP script will not recreate it now.

Comment: I've got only one more silly question, just to understand:
When I make the ajax call, I specify the file and the format like that => $.ajax({
     url: "http://www.somewebsite.com/outputjson.php",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "JSON",
     cache: false,
     success: function(markers) { } });

Now that I've change the format from json to php, should I leave dataType: "JSON"?

Comment: Yep, from the browser's perspective, it is still receiving JSON. It does not know (and does not need to know) that PHP is involved.